# White line glitch (25% sized divs)

Tags: jquery, html, css, joomla

I'm building on this new project, but I encountered a unknown (glitch?) thingy in css.
this is the website [>here<](http://developer.yvbakker.eu)

The problem is as following: on the right side of the 2nd image, there is a glitchy white line. In google chrome it is not visible, the image only extends out of its border when hovering over it. In safari however a 1/2px white line appears when not hovering over, and disappears on hover.

There were originally 4 divs in the width of the page, each 25% (i had the white line here as well). Now i've added a 5th (in the overflow:scroll). Still with the same problem.

Anyone knows how to improve my code so that this messy line is gone forever?

EDIT: it's my project, for a company, but I have permission to share any of its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's a rounding error, as each div.block is set to 315.25px wide. Try setting it to an integer.

Comment: okay, so that's the reason, but then it wouldn't be responsive (as far as it goes) anymore, would it? Any solutions to that? EDIT: nevermind probably a javascript workaround (unless you have other suggestions)

Comment: Yes it would, it just wouldn't be *fluid*

Comment: I think it could be a possible bug with Safari. I am using Safari 5.1.7 on Windows, however it might work on Mac, not too sure. In you enable the web console on Safari and drag it higher up, you will see the white gap disappears.